# How to get Application instance in react native android native code?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a react native android app. I want to get the current ReactNativeApplication instance, people use to get application instance with `com.facebook.react.common.ApplicationHolder.getApplication()`, but now this method is deprecated, so is there any alternative now?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. For the time being I'm using something like

```
// imports up here

let app; // make a global variable

function calledFromiOSFramework() {
    // the 'this' is not longer bound to the 'App'
    console.log(app); // a working reference to 'App'
}

export default class App extends Component {
    app = this;

    render() {
        return(/*...*/)
    }
}
```

Nothing elegant but it works.